# AD5246 I2C adjustable resistor

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, embedded, linear-regulator

does anyone know what is typical life cycle of AD5246 i2c resistor? How many times MCU can write into his register? Any information is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no typical life. MCU can write as many times as you can think of. The value is not stored into any non-volatile memory and the value is always reset to midpoint on powerup. You can verify this information from the datasheet of the chip.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you explain me which type of memory AD5246 use to store i2c result (for example I write 100 to AD5246 so where is that value stored, which type of memory). I know that on powerup AD5246 is on midpoint

Comment: What does it matter which type of memory it is, as long at it stores the data? It could simply be a bunch of flip-flops.

Comment: Ok I'm just curious thats why